# Perl on windows wont let me replace contents inside a file

Tags: perl

So I have a script that renames some contents inside a file

```
local @ARGV = 'myfile';
local $^I = '';
while (<>) {
  s/oldtext/newttext/g;
 print;
}
```

Whenever i run it locally on my macbook it works, but when i run it locally on windows using cmd it gives me the following error: Can't do inplace edit without backup at ..

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows requires that you specify a backup extension.

Just specify a value for `$^I` and then optionally delete the backup after processing the file.

```
local @ARGV = 'myfile';
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    s/oldtext/newttext/g;
    print;
}
unlink "myfile$^I"; # Optionally delete backup
```