# Disable saving backup files in Perl edit-in-place (for Windows)

Tags: windows, perl

I've a perl file **changes.pl** already. I can run *changes.pl* via **cmd command**. I'm looking for disabling *saving backup files* option. I've tried **cmd command 1** and **1a**. But, I get **result** from running any of both.

**changes.pl**

```
BEGIN {
    @ARGV = map glob("\"$_\""), @ARGV;
}

s/a/b/g;
s/c/d/g;
s/e/f/g;
```

**cmd command**

```
perl -i.bak -p changes.pl My/Files/Directory/*.txt
```

**cmd command 1**

```
perl -i -p changes.pl My/Files/Directory/*.txt
```

**cmd command 1a** (back-slash version of *cmd command 1*)

```
perl -i -p changes.pl My\Files\Directory\*.txt
```

**Result**

> I get nothing at all. The cmd command doesn't terminate even.

**Note:**

- I'm using Perl on Windows.
- I've gotten **changes.pl** and **cmd command** from Borodin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774619/4123648) on a previous question of mine.

Comment: Does it do anything at all with command 1? Might the forward slashes in your path on Windows be a problem? Try using backslashes instead.

Comment: @simbabque I've tried the forward slashes. I get nothing at all for both back and forward slashes versions. The cmd command doesn't terminate even.

Comment: Maybe there are a lot of files and it takes really long?

Comment: What is that backslash-doublequote thing supposed to do? What's wrong with plain `@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV;`

Comment: @simbabque No, I test on three files only. Also **cmd command** works fine and quickly. But it creates backup files.

Comment: @choroba Glob patterns are split on whitespace: `perl -E'say for map glob, @ARGV' "foo bar"` This code handles paths containing whitespace.

Comment: Also see [Perl on windows wont let me replace contents inside a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25248853/176646)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-place editing works slightly different on Windows.  On a *nix system you can leave off the ext from the -i switch and the backup file will be unlinked after the edit.  But, on Windows the ext is required and therefore the backup file is retained.  On Windows, you'll need to manually delete the backup(s) after the edit.

Comment: Might be worth adding - this is because of a limitation in Windows which doesn't exist in Unix - in Unix you can open a file, then delete/rename - and because it's open, the data still exists and is readable (until you close it). On Windows this doesn't apply - the file once opened cannot be overwritten/deleted until it's closed.